# How to convert list element to textblock in C++ visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-store-apps

I am using visual studio 2013 to developing windows 8 app. I trying to binding list element data to textblock,But i cannot pass list element to text block by the code.

```
list <string> c1;

 //Insert Data
 c1.push_back("one");
 c1.push_back("two");
 c1.push_back("three");
 c1.push_back("Four");
 c1.push_back("Five");
 c1.push_back("Six");
 c1.push_back("Seven");
 c1.push_back("Eight");
 c1.push_back("Nine");
 c1.push_back("Ten");




 //Random data from list

 int RandNum = 0 + (std::rand() % 10);

 auto en = c1.begin();
 advance(c1.begin(), RandNum);





 ENTEXT->Text = en; //ENTEXT is textblock name
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `en` is an iterator. Try with `*en` and it should work

**Edit:** sorry, i didn't realise theat your textblock was a managed code (aka cli) `String^`:

```
 ENTEXT->Text  = gcnew String(en->c_str());  // convert std::string into String^
```

This conversion from standard strings to microsoft's framework strings is well explained in this article:  [How to convert Standard String to System::String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235219.aspx)

Comment: Ok, please post your exact error message and the precise definition of ENTEXT.

Comment: Hi i think i find out the problem...I need to convert std::string to platform string..then I can pass data to textblock..